# how i insert and update table in one method without form

Tags: laravel-6

i have error if i clik like icons in my project

[image]

**controller**

```
public function like($id,$idpost)
    {
        $like=new like();
        $like->user_id=$id;
        $like->post_id=$idpost;
        $like->save();
        $post=Post::find($idpost);
        $jumlah=Post::where('id',$idpost)->value('like');
        $post->like=$jumlah+1;
        $post->save();
        return redirect('post/'.$like->post_id);
    }
```

**route**

```
Route::post('like/{id}/{idpost}', 'HomeController@like')->name('likes');
```

**views**

```
<a href="{{url('like')}}/{{ Auth::user()->id }}/{{ $detail->id }}"><i style="color: #ed4956; font-size: 25px;" class="fa fa-heart"></i></a>
```

**Database**

[image]

Comment: `Route::post` means passing one more parameter in controller method `public function like(Request $request, $id,$idpost)`